# How to display an image inside of fullcalendar day

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

We are using Fullcalendar JS V5 in a Asp.net Core6 application.

My fullcalendar events have a custom property that can contain a string to an image tag.

I do the following in the EventDidMount event because the image will be different for each day.

However, my image tag does not display my image in the calendar. It displays the "broken" image picture instead.

How can we display a day specific HTML element inside of fullcalendar?

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
  info.el.innerHTML = '<img src="~/images/myimage.png">';
  OR
  info.el.innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.myCustomTag;
}
```

Comment: `It displays the "broken" image picture instead`...have a look in your browser's network tool when you're loading the page, and find the request to that image, and see what HTTP status it returned. If you get a 404 then probably you specified the wrong URL (e.g. I'm not sure what you think the `~` is doing in your URL - is that really your folder name?). Or maybe it's a permissions issue, something like that. It doesn't sound like it's anything at all to do with fullCalendar.

Comment: Is there actually an image at the path `~/images/myimage.png` ?